# How to get both image or video from gallery in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to access the gallery and pick image or video on user choice.

I am building an app where user can upload image or video when they click on the gallery icon. I have used ImagePicker but with ImagePicker I will have to make two separate icon for photo and video. I just want one icon for accessing the gallery and to get video or photo in return.

```
IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(FontAwesome5.getIconData('file-video')),
                  iconSize: 52.0,
                  onPressed: () =>
                      ImagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery),
                )
```

Comment: did you find a way to do it?

Comment: Did anyone find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use filepicker plugin

[image]

> **FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
> type: FileType.any ,
> allowCompression: false,
> );**

Write code as i have shown in the image. After getting image/ video i am checking if it ends with .jpg or .png performing crop while in else performing what i want after video is selected.

Comment: its not working into ios

Comment: one minor tweak to this code. type should be FileType.media in other to get both Image and Video

Answer (score 0):

For accessing to camera and video with only on click you have to use extension "camera" from pub.dev not "image_picker".

Comment: using this package you can't open photo and video toghether from one place

Answer (score 0):

Try this package:
https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker

It is a feature-rich package. It has features like picking single or multiple files, with extensions filtering support.